# Flask-sqlalchemy broken pipe error 32 with mysql and flask-login

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

Broken pipe (error 32) from mysql to flask-sqlalchemy on initial page load (login screen using flask-login), second request works. Site will continue to work for hours, then fail again.

Connection is through mysql+pymysql url

Database is local mysql 5.7 server on a ubuntu 18.04 machine
Site is hosted through gunicorn

Site is using blueprints.

```
Flask==1.0.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0
Flask-Login==0.4.1
```

site was is built from:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

In config.py
    SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE=300

from mysql db:
    wait_timeout = 28800

From /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
    max_allowed_packet = 100M

From other threads on here, sqlalchemy is performing the session closure, so I do not have anything in a after_request function.

I have gone to the third page of google with the following searches:

- flask-sqlalchemy broken pipe
- mysql sqlalchemy broken pipe
- flask-login mysql broken pipe

  2019-06-15 10:48:43,061 ERROR: Exception on /user/login [POST] [in /srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1761]
   11 Traceback (most recent call last):
   12   File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 713, in _write_bytes
   13     self._sock.sendall(data)
   14 BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Simplified site:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
login = LoginManager()
login.login_view = 'user.login'

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app)
    login.init_app(app)

    from app.main import mod_main
    app.register_blueprint(mod_main, url_prefix='/')

    from app.user import mod_user
    app.register_blueprint(mod_user, url_prefix='/user')
```

I had this site on AWS running on a 16.04 VM for 2 years, then I recently migrated to a 18.04 server and upgraded all my flask/python modules.

I have yet to go through each of the module versions to confirm why this behaviour now occurs.

EDIT

Full stack trace (removed email address and hash where 'ABC' and 'XYZ' are)

```
2019-06-15 10:48:43,061 ERROR: Exception on /user/login [POST] [in /srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1761]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 713, in _write_bytes
    self._sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 771, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(packet)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 718, in _write_bytes
    "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/troopnet/app/user/routes.py", line 519, in login
    user = User().authenticate(form.email.data, form.password.data).first()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3215, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3007, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3317, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 128, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1244, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 552, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 771, in _execute_command
    self._write_bytes(packet)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 718, in _write_bytes
    "MySQL server has gone away (%r)" % (e,))
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2006, "MySQL server has gone away (BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))")
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password 
FROM users 
WHERE users.email = %(email_1)s AND users.password = %(password_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: {'email_1': 'ABC', 'password_1': 'XYZ', 'param_1': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
2019-06-15 10:48:47,064 ERROR: Exception on /user/login [POST] [in /srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1761]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1177, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 463, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/troopnet/app/user/routes.py", line 519, in login
    user = User().authenticate(form.email.data, form.password.data).first()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3215, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3007, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3317, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 128, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1177, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 463, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password
FROM users 
WHERE users.email = %(email_1)s AND users.password = %(password_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: [{}]]
2019-06-15 10:48:50,638 ERROR: Exception on /user/login [POST] [in /srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1761]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1177, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 463, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/troopnet/app/user/routes.py", line 519, in login
    user = User().authenticate(form.email.data, form.password.data).first()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3215, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3007, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3317, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 128, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1177, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 463, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password
FROM users 
WHERE users.email = %(email_1)s AND users.password = %(password_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: [{}]]
2019-06-15 10:48:56,354 ERROR: Exception on /user/login [POST] [in /srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py:1761]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1177, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 463, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/srv/troopnet/app/user/routes.py", line 519, in login
    user = User().authenticate(form.email.data, form.password.data).first()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3215, in first
    ret = list(self[0:1])
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3007, in __getitem__
    return list(res)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3317, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3342, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 128, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1177, in _execute_context
    conn = self._revalidate_connection()
  File "/srv/troopnet/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 463, in _revalidate_connection
    "Can't reconnect until invalid "
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) Can't reconnect until invalid transaction is rolled back
[SQL: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.password AS users_password
FROM users 
WHERE users.email = %(email_1)s AND users.password = %(password_1)s 
 LIMIT %(param_1)s]
[parameters: [{}]]
```

Comment: [connections.py", line 713](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/connections.py#L713) is reading a query result, odd to have a failure here. What PyMYSQL version, What MySQL version? Is it a slow query? Can you include the full backtrace? Does the MySQL server have anything in its error log (aka did it crash)? Does the same query directly into mysql without SQLAlchemy or PyMYSQL work correctly?

Comment: added full stack trace. Will attempt query by hand tomorrow night, then again with just pymysql. MySQL error log: Got timeout reading communications packets

Comment: Query is not slow (well on second post when it actually works) MySQL Version: 5.7, PyMySQL version: 0.9.3

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment of the recent upgrade of dependencies, I think that the problem is with the version of Flask-Login.

I had the same issue on a different, but similar Flask build (using the same dependencies). There is an issue of how users sessions are handled by flask_login version 0.4.1 (issue tracker [here](https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed)).

The problem went away when I upgraded to the below:

```
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask==1.1.2
```

note you may also need the below (don't install the latest 1.0.1 as it didn't work in my case):

```
Werkzeug==0.16.1
```

If the above doesn't help you may want to go through the below list (didn't work in my case):

- https://www.cnblogs.com/lesliexong/p/8654615.html <- you may have to use google translate

Good luck!